# Angular template not rendering

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, custom-component, angular-library

Right now I am creating a library (my-custom-library) and a project in which we'll use that library (called my-Project)

The requirement is, that within my-project I have to use my-custom-library, extended with templates, like this (my-project's app.component.html):

```
<my-custom-library>
   <ng-template #myTemplate>
      <div>Some static content for now</div>
   </ng-template>
</my-custom-library>
```

The reason for this is, that in my-custom-library they want to have template-able components, where the template is given from the outside (in this case from my-project).

Within my-custom-library I'm supposed to access the given template(s) and pass them to the corresponding components. This I'm trying to achieve (my-custom-project's app.component.ts)

```
@ContentChild("myTemplate") myTemplateRef?: TemplateRef<any>;
```

(my-custom-project's app.component.html)

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="myTemplateRef"></ng-container>
```

My problem is, that the contentChild is always empty, the template never renders. The structure itself I think is working, since when I'm moving this same structure within just one project and use it there everything works fine, the contentChild gets its value and "my template" is rendered.
One more information, I don't know if its useful but my-custom-library is created like this (my-custom-library's app.module.ts):

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    const customElement = createCustomElement(AppComponent, { injector: this.injector });
    customElements.define('my-custom-library', customElement);
  }
}
```

What could cause this issue? Is it even possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, Apparently ngTemplateOutlet does not work with angular elements. but you can try content projection without ngTemplateOutlet and it works fine.

e.g

```
<my-custom-library>
  <div placeholder1></div>
</my-custom-library>
```

and you can define placeholder1 within your angular element (my-custom-library)

e.g

```
<div>
/*your angular my-custom-library code here */

 /* the content you want to inject from outside of your angular elements*/
  <ng-content select="[placeholder1]"></ng-content>
</div>
```

Note: you can also do nesting of your angular elements as well using this, but with this approach you have to make sure that ng-content is not affect by any ngif condition, because your angular element can project the content from outside but it can not regenerate projection based on your conditions. those conditions should be added from where you are projecting content.